# Can I alert the user from the route/middleware?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, routes

I am using the route to check if a token is valid or not. If it isn't I route the user to the log in page. I want to let the users know they're being logged out either as an **alert** or on the **page**.

What happens is a user clicks on ***Link A*** (to take them to another page on the website), the route calls a `validate.js` file:

**route.js**

```
var checkToken = require('../validate.js');

router.use(checkToken.checkToken);
```

> This then calls the validate.js file which makes a HTTP call to check
>   if the token is valid, if it isn't it redirects the user to the Login
>   page:

**validate.js**

```
var checkToken = function(req, res, next) {
if (config.enableTokenValidation) {

var usersToken = req.user.token;

validateToken(receivedToken, req.requestId, function(err, response, body) {
  if (err || response.statusCode != 200) {

    console.log("Error, token is not valid");
    res.redirect("/auth/logout/");
  } else {

    return next();
  }

});
```

How can I send a message to the `loginView.js`  file so that I can display the error in the front end (or create an alert)? 
But as this happens in the middleware and it is other routes to other pages within the program that trigger the validation check, the login page doesn't make the check and therefore I can't get the response there to alert the user.

If there any way of achieving this using the way I'm going about it, or are there any other ways I can go about it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
res.redirect();
```

Why do not you send an error message like

```
res.status('401').send({error:'Invalid Token'});
```

Then you can take the necessary steps in the **errorHandler()** of the api call.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object that contains a method that fires an Alert message (or a change in your HTML, if you want to change the view). Then you use yourObject.method from the Frontend.